# How Can I Exclude Specific Records Correctly - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, filter

I have a table with Clients and their labels (saved in a single column separated by comma).
I need to find a way to EXCLUDE clients with **SDRC** label.

```
CREATE TABLE FakeData
(
    ClientId INT, 
    ClientLabels VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO FakeData
VALUES (1, 'ABA, SDRC, California'),
       (2, 'SLP, Texas, SDRC (0-3)'),
       (3, 'ABA, SDRC (0-3), SDRC, Virginia'),
       (4, 'OT'),
       (5, 'ABA, SDRC (6+)'),
       (6, 'SLP, SDRC, Texas, SDRC (12+)')

SELECT * FROM FakeData
```

| ClientId | ClientLabels |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABA, SDRC, California |
| 2 | SLP, Texas, SDRC (0-3) |
| 3 | ABA, SDRC (0-3), SDRC, Virginia |
| 4 | OT |
| 5 | ABA, SDRC (6+) |
| 6 | SLP, SDRC, Texas, SDRC (12+) |

The output I need:

| ClientId | ClientLabels |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | SLP, Texas, SDRC (0-3) |
| 4 | OT |
| 5 | ABA, SDRC (6+) |

I was thinking of using `STRING_SPLIT`, however it did not work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM FakeData
WHERE 'SDRC' NOT IN (SELECT VALUE 
                     FROM STRING_SPLIT(FakeData.ClientLabels, ','))
```

And obviously below code will not work as well.

```
SELECT * 
FROM FakeData
WHERE FakeData.ClientLabels NOT LIKE '%SDRC%'
```

Comment: Just don't store data as delimited strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM FakeData
WHERE 'SDRC' NOT IN (SELECT TRIM(VALUE) FROM STRING_SPLIT(FakeData.ClientLabels, ','))
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/717fc/3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `STRING_SPLIT` as a table:

```
SELECT ClientId, ClientLabels
  FROM @FakeData
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ClientLabels, ',') s
 GROUP BY ClientId, ClientLabels
 HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN TRIM(value) = 'SDRC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Re-aggregating it after making your comparisons. To alter the filter just add or remove values in the case statement.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way if you *must* store data like this, would be to use a *like* match

```
select * 
from FakeData
where Concat(', ', ClientLabels, ', ') not like '%, SDRC, %';
```